# How to keep parameter list in a variable

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a script `internal.ps1` which accepts certain params:

```
param ($paramA, $paramB)
Write-Host $PSBoundParameters
```

And a script `caller.ps1` that calls it:

```
.\internal -paramA A -paramB B
```

It works great:

```
PS C:\temp> .\caller
[paramA, A] [paramB, B]    <<<< bounded to both params
```

However, in caller I want to keep the parameters to internal in a var, and use it later. However, that doesn't work:

```
$parms = "-paramA A -paramB B"
# Later...
.\internal $parms

Result: [paramA, A -paramB B]   <<<<< All got bounded to ParamA
```

Neither does using an array:

```
$parms = @("A", "B")
# Later...
.\internal $parms

Result: [paramA, System.Object[]]  <<<< Again, all bound to ParamA
```

How can I accomplish this? Note that the actual commandline is more complex, and may have unknown length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [splatting operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) (@) should do what you need.
Consider first this simple function:

```
function foo($a, $b) { "===> $a + $b" }
```

Calling with explicit arguments yields what you would expect:

```
foo "hello" "world"
===> hello + world
```

Now put those two values in an array; passing the normal array yields *incorrect* results, as you have observed:

```
$myParams = "hello", "world"
foo $myParams
===> hello world +
```

But splat the array instead and you get the desired result:

```
foo @myParams
===> hello + world
```

This works for scripts as well as for functions. Going back to your script, here is the result:

```
 .\internal @myParams
[paramA, hello] [paramB, world]
```

Finally, this will work for an arbitrary number of parameters, so know a priori knowledge of them is needed.

Answer (score 0):

`powershell -file c:\temp\test.ps1  @("A","B")`

or

`powershell -command "c:\temp\test.ps1" A,B`

Answer (score 0):

Your script expects 2 arguments, but your previous attempts pass just a single one (a string and an array respectively). Do it like this:

```
$parms = "A", "B"
#...
.\internal.ps1 $parm[0] $parm[1]
```

Comment: Ok, but how would I use that when I don't know the length of the params? And can I have the $parms var somehow express the binding of paramA to A, etc. (see edited question for usage)?